# A diophantine definition of the Kleene star

Tags: logic, computer-science, diophantine-equations, computability

Let $f(x \, | \, y_1, \dots, y_n)$ be a Diophantine polynomial that generates the Diophantine set $F$.  By [Matiyasevich](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Matiyasevich_theorem), the set $F^*$ (Kleene star of $F$) is also Diophantine.  My question: how can we express the Diophantine polynomial $f^*$ that generates $F^*$ in terms of $f$?

Comment: How are you coding concatenation here?

Comment: Anyway, I doubt there is anything more enlightening than going through one of the standard proofs of the theorem, as in Matiyasevich's book, for example. Whatever comes out, is a function of $f$ but nothing nice/short to describe.